# MVC return RedirectToAction("Index") throws HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

There are a bunch of similar questions, but none of the answers have worked me.  I'm try to return 'RedirectToAction("Index");' which is in the same controller, from 'public ActionResult Create()' when the user is not authorized to create a new widget. I have no other folders with the name Index, although there are other 'Public ActionResults Index()' functions in other controllers. Any suggestions wouls be greatly appreciated...thanks

Comment: show your code in its entirety. are you sure you are referencing the CORRECT controller you want to redirect to also?

Comment: Run fiddler and see what requests and responses the browser and the server exchange.  If you cannot make sense of them, post the here

Comment: Sounds to me like you have an `AuthorizeAttribute` at the top of your controller .. making `Index` also require authorization - so redirecting to that is pointless. You'll need to show some code though.

Comment: As Simon says (punny), but also check to see if you have added `AuthorizeAttribute` in your `FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters` method, which applies to the entire site.

Comment: Are you using IIS? If so you should check what authentication modes you have enabled, e.g. Windows authentication, basic etc.

Comment: Thanks everyone...I'm investigating all your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to replicate your scenario to no avail. 
New MVC5 project with a Test controller tried both Authorize attribute on both actions just to test, but all they do is actually redirect you to the login page if you are not authorized to view the resource.

**HTTP 403.14 is a code for directory listing denied.** 
It sounds to me that you are redirecting to a URL that is not being handled by the MVC and instead is being picked by your IIS express, which by default doesn't allow listing of directory contents.

So questions to consider are: 
1: what is the exact url that you are calling. 
2: How is your routing setup, do you have any custom routes ? order of the routes is important.

To be able to provide you with  more info please do post the controller code as well as your RouteConfig.cs file.

Here is the test code.

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    // GET: Test
       [Authorize] // just redirects back to login page if you call create action. 
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }


    // GET: Test/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index"); 
    }
```

}

Here is the routes config file. unchanged.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Comment: You were correct the Requested URL http://localhost:50166/Content/, was wrong. By changing RedirectToAction("Index");  to RedirectToAction("/Index"); the request was redirected to  http://localhost:50166/ContentController/, the correct URL.  Thanks again for spending time on this.